# pymysql retreiving data goes wrong

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I have this problem when i want to retreive data from my database.

```
aa= pymysql.connect(host='',user='',passwd='',db='',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        mm = aa.cursor()
        cursor = aa.cursor()

mm.execute('SELECT Logintime FROM sportschool WHERE username = %s AND Wachtwoord = %s',(username,password))
logouttime = mm.fetchone()
            print logouttime
```

the print loggouttime prints this:
(datetime.timedelta(0, 65912),)
But i only need the unix code so in this case 65912
i already tried it with and withouth dictcursor but that doenst work

hope someone can help me to get the right infromation from my table.

Comment: Not sure what you think has gone wrong. Try `print(logouttime[0].total_seconds())`. But this is a timedelta object that represents the time difference between two datetimes, so that possibly represents the total time logged in

Comment: no i have an column called loggedintime loggedouttime and totaltime
When i logout i set the logouttime but then i want that the totaltime is the time difference between the loggedintime and the loggedouttime

Comment: Ok but that is an issue in how your database is set up then, because you are getting a timedelta which, as I already said, is a time _difference_ in `Logintime`. The question is confusing anyway because your SELECT is for Logintime but you call the result logouttime

Answer (score 0):

You can use the total_seconds method in datetime type

```
print datetime.timedelta(0, 65912).total_seconds()
65912.0
```

Comment: i need the time itself because i need to calculate the difference between when someone logs out and when someone logs in

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your loggouttime is a tuple with datetime.timedelta in it. You need to get the first element of the tuple first, and then convert the timedelta into seconds.

Give the following code a try:

```
    logouttime = mm.fetchone()
    first_log_out_time = logouttime[0]
    log_out_time_seconds = first_log_out_time.seconds
    print(log_out_time_seconds)
```

Comment: i get this error(see pastebin)
https://pastebin.com/aBAS1UzN
i need the time itself because i need to calculate the difference between when someone logs out and when someone logs in

Comment: could you please do `print(logouttime)` and print(type(logouttime))?

Comment: I think the problem may be some of your data does not have value so that you cannot index it. If you are looping the data, use a `try` / `except` to see which records went wrong